# Nutch 1.14 failed ScoringFilter.java

Tags: java, maven, nutch

I have an error when i execute `mvn -X install` or `mvn -e clean install`.
I have already tried `rm /root/.m2/repository` but not affect this error.
I have configure maven $ java OPTS (on RHEL6, java 1.8).

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.577 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-16T10:27:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/517M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project nutch: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: syntax error @[226,36] in file:/opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project nutch: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: syntax error @[226,36] in file:/opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: syntax error @[226,36] in file:/opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error @[226,36] in file:/opt/NUTCH/nutch-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyerror (Parser.java:1018)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyparse (Parser.java:1324)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.parse (Parser.java:999)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource (JavaDocBuilder.java:353)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource (JavaDocBuilder.java:388)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource (JavaDocBuilder.java:384)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder$2.visitFile (JavaDocBuilder.java:474)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk (DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.scan (DirectoryScanner.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSourceTree (JavaDocBuilder.java:471)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSourceTree (JavaDocBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.java.JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.discoverClasses (JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:712)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.java.JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute (JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:675)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor (DefaultMojoScanner.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute (AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.DescriptorGeneratorMojo.execute (DescriptorGeneratorMojo.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I don't understand because line `@[226,36]` not exist in file `ScoringFilter.java`.

Have you ever had this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you double check which version of the source code are trying to compile? Checking the tag for the 1.14 release (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blame/release-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java#L226) the line seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: I check file ScoringFilter.java and it's the same. 

the beginning of the pom.xml file contains : 
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.nutch</groupId>
  <artifactId>nutch</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.14</version>
  <name>Apache Nutch</name>
  <url>http://nutch.apache.org</url>
  <licenses>

Comment: Nutch is build by ant, not maven, and there is no pom.xml included in the 1.14 source package. Ant can create a pom.xml but it's only used to deploy the artifacts, not to build them.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers but i tried with maven after an failure with ant 
I found pom.xml in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nutch/nutch/1.14

I have an error with ant because he search a strange .jar in tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hello-ivy/working@MYHOSTNAME/hello-ivy-working@MYHOSTNAME.jar